# Sound Engine with good memory management (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio

I'm looking for simple sound engine without advanced effects but with good management of buffers memory. At least it must track all playing sounds, unload not used sound buffers (but keep all currently playing), adjust gain for sound groups. Support of input streaming and compressed formats would be advantage.

PS: FMOD and BASS are good engines but too expensive for these low requirements.

Comment: A little clarification: What kind of sound you want to play? Want to play some MP3 or you want to have system generated sound?

Comment: Only ogg/wav sounds from files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have couple of references those should be helpful to you:

The Kowalski Engine is a real time audio engine written in C, based on a hierarchical mix bus system.

http://kowalski.sourceforge.net/

The CLUNK C++ library provides support for real-time 3D(binaural) sound generation. It puts virtually no limitations on the developer

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clunk/

Easy Objective-C interface to OpenAL, AVAudioPlayer, and audio session management.

https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

I believe this should be helpful to get the solution with the great memory management in place.

Comment: Kowalski Engine seems to be what I'm looking for. I will dig it deeper to check, does it support my requests. The most important thing I need - two functions: `purge_not_used_sounds()` and `simply_load_and_play_sound_file(the_file)`

Comment: Some attention to Kowalski Engine: it uses software sound processing, so may be 'heavy' for iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [CocosDenshion](http://cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq) (part of Cocos2d) to be easy to use and to have a simple memory management.

Comment: I already used it. It doesn't support tracking of playing sounds (so it isn't possible to determine what buffers are "busy" at current moment), and it will take a lot of time to add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/)? It can interface with core-audio for iOS. I strongly recommend it, it has all the main important building blocks for sound synthesis, without any additional stuff (like CLAM), is very lightweight and highly portable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SoundMaster engine](https://github.com/jerminal/SoundMaster).
It's super simple and has good memory management.